# How do you fix the “element not interactable” exception in selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Disclaimer: I found other issues related to this but no solution worked.
When clicking on a button with selenium on python, I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
```

Up until that point, there was no issue. The button is big, right there in the middle of the page, I access it with a unique id. When I move my mouse myself and click on it it works as expected.

Any idea why this may happen?

Comment: Did you mind to share your code?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for different reasons, try the following: 
1- Make sure the element is visible in the viewport.
2- Make sure that there is no element with z-index higher than the target element.
3- Make sure that there is no Tippy menu or flyout menu displayed over it.
4- Make sure that there is no Hidden/Glass element that covers it but you can't see it with your own eyes.

Please let me know if this works